# How to fit Spark's classifier in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-mllib

Guys I have a strange problem...

I'm trying to train multiclass SVM classifier like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, SVMModel> jp = scmap.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, RDD<LabeledPoint>>,Tuple2<String, String>, SVMModel >(){
       @Override
       public Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, SVMModel> call(Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, RDD<LabeledPoint>> tup) 
       {
               SVMWithSGD svmAlg = new SVMWithSGD();
               svmAlg.optimizer()
               .setNumIterations(100)
               .setRegParam(0.1)
               .setUpdater(new SquaredL2Updater());
               final SVMModel model = svmAlg.run(tup._2());
               model.clearThreshold();
               return new Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, SVMModel>(tup._1(), model);

       }
   });
```

But when I'm trying to **collect()** jp - I have this error:

```
15/01/16 20:06:30 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 147, fujitsu11.in.nu): java.lang.NullPointerException: 
        org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD$.slice(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:157)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD.getPartitions(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:97)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
    scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1060)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1092)
    org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:141)
    maven.maven1.App$10.call(App.java:430)
    maven.maven1.App$10.call(App.java:1)
    org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:926)
    org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:926)
    scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$16.apply(RDD.scala:774)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.1 in stage 5.0 (TID 148, fujitsu11.in.nu, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2219 bytes)
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.1 in stage 5.0 (TID 148) on executor fujitsu11.in.nu: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 1]
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.2 in stage 5.0 (TID 149, fujitsu11.in.nu, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2219 bytes)
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.2 in stage 5.0 (TID 149) on executor fujitsu11.in.nu: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 2]
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 150, fujitsu11.in.nu, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2219 bytes)
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 150) on executor fujitsu11.in.nu: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 3]
15/01/16 20:06:30 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 7 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 5
15/01/16 20:06:30 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Failed to run collectAsMap at App.java:452
```

Why I get here NullPointer? I checked several times, that my

```
RDD<LabeledPoint>
```

and

```
Tuple2<String, String>
```

are not null. Maybe it's not capable to train classifier in parallel on workers?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run distributed operations inside distributed operations. But your first `mapToPair` need not be a distributed operation. Just `.par.map` a collection locally on the driver, each of which spawns a distributed operation to fit the model.

Comment: Man, did I get it right?

**mapCol** - is a `List<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, RDD<LabeledPoint>>>`

then:

`List trainedModls = mapСol.parallelStream().map(m -> train(m)).collect(Collectors.toList());` where **train()** - is a function where I train binary classifiers?

Comment: That's looking about right. The idea is that you have a collection of parameters, and map each of them -- in parallel, driver-side -- to a distributed operation that makes a model from those params.

Comment: What if you wanted to train the models with different subsets of the training data as well?